# How do I modify my script to make events added show that I'm available?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to modify my Google Apps Script that takes in my schedule information from a Google Sheet and creates events on my calendar to show what days/when I am working (I don't work regular 8-5 hours, and my schedule changes every week).  The problem I'm running into is that it's creating the events and classifying me as busy during these events, which is causing confusion when other people are trying to schedule meetings with me (showing my entire day blocked as busy).  Is there a way to script it so that it adds events to my calendar but shows me as available?  I've been digging and I feel like it should be simple, but I just can't find anything.

I know the code to create events is cal.CreateEvent(Title, start time, end time, options), but I don't know what options are available.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hey there :) Could you help provide a screenshot/sample sheet of the problem and desired outcome? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The options for `CalendarApp.CreateEvent(title, start time, end time, options)` are documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options) (under "Advanced parameters"), but they do not include whether the user is shown as "available."  It looks like this cannot be done with the CalendarApp service, but if you [enable the advanced Calendar service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services), you can set the availability, which is labeled as ["transparency"](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#transparency).  Something like this:

```
let calEvent = cal.CreateEvent(title, start, end, options)
Calendar.Events.patch({transparency:"transparent"},
  YOUR_CALENDAR_ID,calEvent.getId())
```